# A strong antonym for "dictator"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

Is there a formal antonym for the word "dictator" other than " democratic" to describe a school principal?

Comment: In the political sense, you could use **statesman**, meaning an honorable and generally well-liked politician (Yes, those used to be a thing that existed).  Not sure that could be applied to a school principal, however, thus comment and not an answer.

Comment: [Typist?](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dictate)

Comment: "Doormat" is a term that likely would be applied.

Comment: Hot Licks: Thanks. But you know it won' fit in a formal text.

Comment: it rather depends what you mean by `"dictator"`

Comment: Not all works have antonyms.

Comment: You might be looking for "first among equals".

Comment: "Democratic" is not *remotely* an antonym of "dictator". I hope you realize that makes answering a bit awkward.

Judging by your reactions to the answers, you seem to be asking for terms for a leadership style that considers the input (or the opinions) of others. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 38):

***[Pluralist](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pluralist):***

> - a ​person who ​believes that the ​existence of different ​types of ​people, ​beliefs, and ​opinions within a ​society is a good thing.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: However, a "dictator" does not necessarily mean a "facist dictator". A dictator is just somebody who tells others what to do with a strict level of authority. Therefore, somebody who "believes that the ​existence of different ​types of ​people, ​beliefs, and ​opinions within a ​society is a good thing", and strictly enforces the society to act in this way, could be considered a dictator. It just so happens that many dictators in history have been linked with facism, but that is not the definition of a dictator.

Comment: @Karnivaurus I think you mean "fascist".

Comment: @Karnivaurus is exactly right.  The term "dictator" comes to us from the Roman Empire, where it was originally an honorable term: a person temporarily installed as an absolute leader in times of crisis when decisive action was needed.  It's when the "temporary" part of it isn't observed that being a dictator starts becoming a real problem.

Answer (score 26):

Consider, ***collegial***

> Having authority or power shared among a number of people associated as colleagues
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/collegial)
>
> *On screen, his persona is as flat and colorless as his home state of Indiana, although around the office he's more like a [collegial headmaster](http://articles.latimes.com/2001/apr/09/entertainment/ca-48703), chatty and amiable, yet demanding objectivity from co-workers even when they talk politics by the water cooler.* (Source: LA Times)

Comment: Brad & Elian : Your antonyms are also perfect. Thanks.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense in the context that the OP presents. Other answers may be valid if we were talking about a literal dictator, i.e. a ruler over a nation. But that's not the context here.

Answer (score 15):

A good possibility, I think, is an

> egalitarian,

[meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egalitarian) a person who believes in or promotes equal political, social, and economic rights for all people.

Another possibility is a

> negotiator,

who, rather than saying "My way or the highway," says, "Let's negotiate a win/win outcome; that is, a solution we can both live with."

And finally, related to negotiator is a

> compromiser

or a person who engages in give and take; you know, "you scratch my back and I'll scratch yours." Behind a compromiser's thinking is a quid pro quo (or tit for tat) mentality. A compromiser says, "If you want to get something you've got to give something."

Answer (score 8):

A ***consensualist***, perhaps? (consensual - relating to or involving consent (OED))

Comment: Or "consensus", which can entail the faculty and PTA.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure *democratic* is the right antonym, unless every kid in school has a vote, and can elect the head, the teachers, and vote on school policy. Words that might work for your intended meaning:

- consultative
- collegiate
- inclusive
- collaborative

Comment: I suspect the original poster was referring to the principal vis-a-vis the faculty, not the students.

Answer (score 6):

A school principal is a dictator in the strictest sense.  However, consider **benevolent dictator**.  It's supposedly the best form of government.

If only we could trust power not to corrupt.

Comment: Correct spelling is **benevolent** (google it.) The system will not allow me to make an edit that small.

Comment: or _just ruler_

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't the "strict antonym" be someone who can only *follow* orders? *lackey*, *yes-man*, *acolyte*, *slave*... ?

Comment: IMO, this answer should be a comment.

Comment: I had the exact same thought when I read this question! I'm glad someone pointed this out.  I would add "subject", "servant", "subordinate" to the list of antonyms for a dictator.

Comment: @Alpha3031 this should not be a comment.  It's a very valid answer in it's own right.

Comment: @Alpha3031 no, because I don't just ask what the OP meant, I answer based on this interpretation.

Comment: Because of where we are, I feel compelled to point out that "it's" is always "it is" and "its" is the pronoun.

Comment: Can we prove that the dictator has free will? Without free will, the dictator is also a lackey, yes-man, acolyte, slave.

Comment: We assume we're referring to the true dictator, not his *puppet*, with the term.

Answer (score 1):

**Liberator** could be used as an antonym if you mean that the school became more liberating due to the efforts of a person.
As Wikictionary says:

> A person who frees or liberates.

Comment: "Liberator" has the connotation of a revolutionary, someone overthrowing the powers that be to free the people. If the principal is fighting against the school board or federal authorities, it might be appropriate. But I think the OP here simply means, "one who listens to opinions and advice from others", or "one who lets people under his authority act autonomously".

Answer (score 0):

latitudinarian in a sense:  one who is broadly accepting

Comment: Please add a quote from a dictionary giving the full definition of this word. Name the specific dictionary you used, and link back to it (if feasible).

Answer (score 0):

diplomatic, perhaps (not in the strict sense of referring to a diplomat, but in the sense of being polite, judicious, and sensitive to others)

Answer (score 0):

I would say *anarchist*.  An anarchist (in one definition) being someone who supports the sovereignty of each individual, rather than the soverignty of a dictator, king, or State.  Although many anarchists today refer to themselves are *voluntaryists* to avoid negative connotations of that word.

Comment: At the risk of getting into politics, many anarchists (essentially hard-core libertarians) oppose many forms of "equality".  I mention that because I see it used in other answers and I felt a quick thought deserved a small mention.  Things like economic equality are thought by them to be only achievable when a central power, such as a dictator, acts upon the system to enforce this equality.  So the term may not be as exact as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is NOT what the OP is looking for.  However, I must point out that dictator does have actual antonyms.  They just don't counter the style of leadership.  They counter leadership.

> Antonyms for dictator
>
> - employee
> - follower
> - worker
>
> [thesaurus.com: dictator](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dictator)

Those could describe a school principal, from the perspective of the superintendent.

Answer (score 0):

A ***shepherd*** is someone in command who puts the well-being of their subjects above everything else, sometimes above their own. That’s why it’s a frequent metaphor in religious, especially Christian contexts ([Psalm 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_23)) and it’s the original meaning of *pastor*.